# Unknown Error? - A Column was specified that does not exist

Tags: arcpy, error, cursor, loop

```
shps = [(shp1,"field1"),
        (shp2,"field2")]

for item in shps:
    shp = item[0]
    field = item[1]
    for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(shp, fields='"{0}"'.format(field)):
        if row == MyInVariable:
            sql = '"{0}" = \'{1}\''.format(field,MyInVariable)
            if arcpy.Exists("fl"):
                    arcpy.Delete_management("fl")
            fl = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(shp,"fl",sql)        
            break
    del row
```

The above code produces an error that states: "A column was specified that does not exist." field1 and field2 do exist as columns in shp1 and shp2 respectively. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: What are you talking about? C++, Java, QGIS, GeoTools?

Comment: Python - ArcObjects with python - "arcpy" - Developing a python script tool for an ArcGIS toolbox

Comment: The error occurs on the line: for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(shp, fields='"{0}"'.format(field)):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formatting looks wrong, because

```
>>> field="field1"
>>> '"{0}"'.format(field)
'"field1"'
```

This

```
 "{0}".format(field)
```

will do. However fields=field is even better